# Adding two Strings simultaneously

Tags: java

I want to add two  strings where the output should be like 
if string s1="abc";
String s2="xyzwert"

the output  of the two Strings should be "axbyczwert"

Thanks

Comment: String.charAt index and StringBuilder append use should do the trick.

Comment: if you have only 2 Strings you can concatenate them with (+) operator. s1+s2 would produce what you want

Comment: @MirekSurma Look closely. The contents of each string are interleaved. Straight concatenation won't do

Comment: yes I have tried both the methods but its not working,its showing String out of index exception

Comment: Hi , what if I have my strings like this – String str1="abc"; String str2="xyzwerwer";where number of chars in one of the Strings are more than the other,here I want to get the output as axbyczwerwer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both strings are the same length:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
    sb.append(str1.charAt(i)).append(str2.charAt(i));
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

If one string is longer, you'll need something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int i = 0;
for(int len = Math.min(str1.length(), str2.length()); i < len; i++) {
    sb.append(str1.charAt(i)).append(str2.charAt(i));
}
if(str1.length() != str2.length()) {
    String longerStr = str1.length() > str2.length() ? str1 : str2;
    sb.append(longerStr.substring(i));
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Hi , what if I have my strings like this – String str1="abc"; String str2="xyzwerwer";where number of chars in one of the Strings are more than the other,here I want to get the output as axbyczwerwer

Comment: String s1 = "abc";
    String s2 = "xyzasdasd";
    String s3=s1+s2;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < s3.length(); i++) {
        sb.append(s1.charAt(i)).append(s2.charAt(i));
    }
    String result = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
  }

here I am getting StringOutOfIndex exception

Comment: Wait, where did you get the idea of creating `s3`? Of course it's going out of bounds...

Comment: Not sure what you tried, but it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you.

```
//Check if s1 or s2 is longer, if s1 is longer, set maxLength as s1.length. vice versa
int maxLength = (s1.length() > s2.length()) ? s1.length() : s2.length();
//Default result string
String result = "";
//Loop through the max number of characters based on the result earlier
//Slowly add each character of both s1 and s2 to the result string starting from index0
//This will result in the alternate adding of characters from both strings
for(int i=0; i<maxLength; i++)
{
    //Check if s1 is shorter than the maxLength to prevent index out of range.
    if(i < s1.length())
    {
        result += Character.toString( s1.charAt(i) );
    }

    //Check if s2 is shorter than the maxLength to prevent index out of range.
    if(i < s2.length())
    {
        result += Character.toString( s2.charAt(i) );
    }
}
System.out.println (result);
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Comment: Updated answer with comments

Comment: Sorry if there are any code syntax problems, I normally do my stuff using C#.

Answer (score -1):

This code will do what you want:

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = "xyzwerwer";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
        sb.append(s1.charAt(i));
        sb.append(s2.charAt(i));
    }
    sb.append(s1.substring(s1.length() - (s1.length() - s2.length())));
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        sb.append(s1.charAt(i));
        sb.append(s2.charAt(i));
    }
    sb.append(s2.substring(s2.length() - (s2.length() - s1.length())));
}
String s3 = sb.toString();
System.out.println(s3);
```

Edited the code to work with the newest question.

Comment: Hi , what if I have my strings like this –  String str1="abc";
  String str2="xyzwerwer";where number of chars in one of the Strings are more than the other,here I want to get the output as axbyczwerwer